# Считывание текста из файла в нужной кодировке

Tags: c#

Необходимо считать строки из файла и записать их в массив, а потом отобразить на лейбле. Но почему-то русскую кодировку не распознает. Пробовал и так

```
        using (StreamReader read = File.OpenText("E:\\category.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                category[i] = read.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        label1.Text = category[0].ToUpper();
        label2.Text = category[1].ToUpper();
        label3.Text = category[2].ToUpper();
        label4.Text = category[3].ToUpper();
        label5.Text = category[4].ToUpper();
```

И так

```
        category = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\category.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        label1.Text = category[0].ToUpper();
        label2.Text = category[1].ToUpper();
        label3.Text = category[2].ToUpper();
        label4.Text = category[3].ToUpper();
        label5.Text = category[4].ToUpper();
```

Но получается все равно вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно считать, чтобы получились русские буквы?

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас там `UTF-8`?

Comment: А то похоже на `Windows-1251`

Comment: Ну или шрифт кириллицу не поддерживает.

Comment: @Сергей в Encording нет такой кодировки, как же правильно сделать?

Comment: Сделайте сначала, чтобы работало со стандартным шрифтом типа Arial.

Comment: @Сергей Да действительно, там был не утф8, сохранил в другом формате и стало нормально. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется у вас там не UTF-8, а виндовая 1251.

```
Encoding win1251= Encoding.GetEncoding( "windows-1251" );
category = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\category.txt", win1251);
```

Еще возможно - шрифт у вас не стандартный - и не поддерживает кириллицу.

Comment: Проще наверное `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)`.

Comment: Ну да, не принципиально, впрочем.

Answer (score 0):

**D:\zzz\a.txt**

> Hello World! Привет Мир!
>
> Hello World! Привет Мир!

**Main.cs**

```
using System;
//подключить пространство имен
using System.IO;
//подключить пространство имен для кодировки
using System.Text;
class Program {
public static int Main() {
//путь
string path = @"D:\zzz\a.txt";
//если файл существует
if(File.Exists(path)) {
/*---считывание из файла, 1 вариант---*/
//создаем байтовый поток и привязываем его к файлу
//в конструкторе указываем:
//путь
//кодировка
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8)) {
 string str = null;
while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
Console.WriteLine(str = sr.ReadLine());
}
}
Console.WriteLine("\n");
/*---считывание из файла, 2 вариант---*/
//создаем байтовый поток и привязываем его к файлу
//в конструкторе указываем:
//путь
//кодировка
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8)) {
string str = null;
while((str=sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
Console.WriteLine(str);
}
}
}
//если файл не существует
else {
Console.WriteLine("такой файл не существует");
}
Console.ReadKey();
return 0;
}
}
```

**На экране**

> Hello World! Привет Мир!
>
> Hello World! Привет Мир!

Comment: А теперь сохраните ваш файл в другой кодировке и попробуйте открыть вашим кодом